# LWC Community - File Upload in Record Edit form

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a Lightning Record form in which there is a field which accepts file Upload. I can successfully upload the image the pop-up is greyed out. I don't understand why.

```
        <lightning-file-upload  label="Attachment" accept={acceptedFormats} onuploadfinished={handleUploadFinished} record-id={wired.Id} multiple></lightning-file-upload>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Date_of_Birth__c" ></lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Officical_Language_Preference__c" ></lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Sex__c" ></lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Telephone_home__c" ></lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Work_or_other_telephone_no__c" ></lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Resedential_address__c" ></lightning-input-field> 
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Mailing_Address__c" ></lightning-input-field>
```

and the Js is as follows

get acceptedFormats() {
return ['.pdf', '.png','.jpg'];
}
handleUploadFinished(event){
const uploadedFiles = event.detail.files;
alert("No. of files uploaded : " + uploadedFiles.length);
}

[image]

Comment: Did you try to inspect?

Comment: I did, it does not get into any of the method.

Comment: Can you try to find out the div which is greying out the whole screen, in the inspector?